# Monotouch.Dialog: ScopeBar hidden by SectionHeader

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar, monotouch.dialog

Using MonoTouch.Dialog I add a simple table and add a ScopeBar:

```
     this.Style = UITableViewStyle.Plain;
     this.EnableSearch = true;
     this.AutoHideSearch = false;
     this.SearchPlaceholder = "Search".t();
     UISearchBar sb = TableView.TableHeaderView as UISearchBar;
     if (sb != null)
     {
        sb.ScopeButtonTitles = new string[] { "Girl".t(),"Boy".t(),"All".t() };
        sb.ShowsScopeBar = true;
        sb.SizeToFit();
     }
```

Looks good:

[image]

When I set the Section and give it a Title, the Section appears on top of the scope bar:

```
Section secMain = new Section("Top 100".t());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to change MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController and make `void SetupSearch()` protected virtual.

Then, in your controller override the SetupSearch method with the code that follows. The downside to this approach is that you have to use a custom search delegate. But from seeing the response to some of your other questions, it appears you are already doing that.

```
    protected override void SetupSearch()
    {
        SearchBar = new UISearchBar(new RectangleF (0, 0, TableView.Bounds.Width, 90))
        {
            Delegate = new MySearchBarDelegate(this),
            Placeholder = "Search".t(),
            ShowsScopeBar = true,
            ScopeButtonTitles = new [] { "Girl".t(),"Boy".t(),"All".t() },
            SelectedScopeButtonIndex = 0,
        };

        TableView.TableHeaderView = SearchBar;                  
    }

    public class MySearchBarDelegate : UISearchBarDelegate
    {
        MyViewController _container;

        public SearchDelegate (MyViewController container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public override void SelectedScopeButtonIndexChanged (UISearchBar searchBar, int index)
        {
            _container.SearchScopeChanged(searchBar, index);
        }

        public override void OnEditingStarted (UISearchBar searchBar)
        {
            searchBar.ShowsCancelButton = true;
            _container.StartSearch ();
        }

        public override void OnEditingStopped (UISearchBar searchBar)
        {
            searchBar.ShowsCancelButton = false;
            _container.FinishSearch ();
        }

        public override void TextChanged (UISearchBar searchBar, string searchText)
        {
            _container.PerformFilter (searchText ?? "");
        }

        public override void CancelButtonClicked (UISearchBar searchBar)
        {
            searchBar.ShowsCancelButton = false;
            _container.SearchBar.Text = "";
            _container.FinishSearch ();
            searchBar.ResignFirstResponder ();
        }

        public override void SearchButtonClicked (UISearchBar searchBar)
        {
            _container.SearchButtonClicked (searchBar.Text);
        }
    }
```